# why request headers are exactly the same, but different Ajax content can be received?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http, http-headers

When i open "http://aip.scitation.org/toc/apl/current", the website of a journal called applied physics letters, there are quite a lot AJAX fields on that page. Every time I click "show abstract", the abstract of the corresponding article will show up. I know that using "inspect elements"`
-"network", filter by XHR, i can get the request header when i click "show abstract"

The question is when I click different "show abstract" on that page, every time the request headers, cookies are exactly the same.  If the request headers are always the same, how can the server know which abstract content it should deliver to the browser? Then I looked for the difference, the only difference is as the screen capture shows, the "params" tab contains different information. But information in "params" has not been delivered to server, right? I am not sure on this.
I am designing a web crawler using python3 and based on what I know, I use urllib.request to deliver Headers to website server.
[screen capture of network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnHTX.png)
Can some tell me how is the logic behind this? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is how the application will behave. For Ajax or let it be any request you can see the parameters passed in params/formbody or in query string. this is where the input is passed to the server based on these inputs server will respond back to client.

Generally headers/ Cookies will store application level data like tokens, authentication related content etc. In the page you mentioned also should work same way.

If you need some code example refer http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/  if you notice a property called "data" that is used to send input and not headers. usually headers are key value pairs which has content type, length etc.

The jquery ajax link and examples should get you started